# Freezer-scheduler Critical Error: Incremental nova backup is not supported

Tags: backup, openstack, nova

I have some issues with my freeze-scheduler job.
I try to backup one instance and I got this error :

```
2020-12-21 14:15:06.512 4068 INFO freezer.main [-] Begin freezer agent process with args: ['/usr/local/bin/freezer-agent', '--metadata-out', '-', '--config', '/tmp/tmp8QjMfv']
2020-12-21 14:15:06.512 4068 INFO freezer.main [-] log file at /home/debian/log/scheduler/backup_sched_NL_bkp.log
2020-12-21 14:15:06.515 4068 INFO freezer.openstack.osclients [-] Authenticating with Keystone version: None, auth_url: http://192.168.10.174:5000/v3, username: admin, project: admin
2020-12-21 14:15:07.083 4068 INFO freezer.job [-] Validating args for the backup job.
2020-12-21 14:15:07.083 4068 ERROR freezer.main [-] Incremental nova backup is not supported: ValueError: Incremental nova backup is not supported
2020-12-21 14:15:07.083 4068 ERROR freezer.main Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-12-21 14:15:07.083 4068 ERROR freezer.main   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/freezer/main.py", line 270, in main
2020-12-21 14:15:07.083 4068 ERROR freezer.main     freezer_main(backup_args)
2020-12-21 14:15:07.083 4068 ERROR freezer.main   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/freezer/main.py", line 137, in freezer_main
2020-12-21 14:15:07.083 4068 ERROR freezer.main     return run_job(backup_args, storage)
2020-12-21 14:15:07.083 4068 ERROR freezer.main   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/freezer/main.py", line 146, in run_job
2020-12-21 14:15:07.083 4068 ERROR freezer.main     'exec': job.ExecJob}[conf.action](conf, storage)
2020-12-21 14:15:07.083 4068 ERROR freezer.main   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/freezer/job.py", line 58, in __init__
2020-12-21 14:15:07.083 4068 ERROR freezer.main     self._validate()
2020-12-21 14:15:07.083 4068 ERROR freezer.main   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/freezer/job.py", line 153, in _validate
2020-12-21 14:15:07.083 4068 ERROR freezer.main     raise ValueError("Incremental nova backup is not supported")
2020-12-21 14:15:07.083 4068 ERROR freezer.main ValueError: Incremental nova backup is not supported
2020-12-21 14:15:07.083 4068 ERROR freezer.main
2020-12-21 14:15:07.084 4068 CRITICAL freezer.main [-] Run freezer agent process unsuccessfully
2020-12-21 14:15:07.084 4068 CRITICAL freezer.main [-] Critical Error: Incremental nova backup is not supported
```

**And as you can see below I actually do ask for an not-incremental backup :**

```
{
   "job_actions":[
      {
         "freezer_action":{
            "action":"backup",
            "backup_name":"backup_sched_NL",
            "mode":"nova",
            "engine":"nova",
            "no-incremental":"true",
            "nova-inst-id":"<my id>",
            "storage":"local",
            "container":"/tmp/freezer/scheduler/",
            "log_file": "/home/debian/log/scheduler/backup_sched_NL_bkp.log"

},
         "max_retries":3,
         "max_retries_interval":60

}

],
   "job_schedule":{
      "schedule_interval":"3 hours",
      "schedule_start_date":"2020-11-17T10:50:00"


},
   "description":"schedule_backup nova local"
}
```

If anyone has an idea...